# Unable to create a new page IONIC 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I updated my project from ionic 4 to 6 and after fixing everything.
not able to create a new page using `ionic generate page`

but it shows an error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Package "@ionic/cordova-builders" was found but does not support schematics.
```

by far I've already deleted node_modules and intstalled all the packages again.

unable to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@ionic/angular-toolkit` for the schematics.

```
{ 
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  },
}
```